# Disable Data Connection from code in Android Lollipop or above

Tags: android, android-networking

Is there a way do disable/ enable data connection on an Android that has the version Lollipop or above (in code)?

Answer (score 0):

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;


if (currentapiVersion >= 21) {
    // Do what u want (eneble or disaqble) eg. u want to enable in this condition

 Method dataMtd = ConnectivityManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", boolean.class);
            dataMtd.setAccessible(true);
            dataMtd.invoke(connectivityManager, true);




} else {

     // Do what u want (eneble or disaqble) eg. u want to disable here


Method dataMtd =     ConnectivityManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", boolean.class);
dataMtd.setAccessible(false);
dataMtd.invoke(connectivityManager, false);
}
```

Comment: The answer is not that simple. I already tried that (It didn't worked) and the result is this:
[MainActivity](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jI7FR.jpg), [Searching for setMobileDataEnabled method in ConnectivityManager class](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RS3t3.jpg), [The permissions in AndroidManifest](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9oQdg.jpg), [My current verion of Android](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jxwbP.jpg)